# Storing points from a path objects on a ArrayList Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, path, addition

I have manage to draw a rectangle using the path object but I have problems adding the points into a point ArrayList. The x and y depends on the touch coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> pList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();

public void addRectangle() {

    Path path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(x, y);
    path.lineTo(x+25, y);
    path.lineTo(x+25, y+5);
    path.lineTo(x, y+5);

    path.close();

    pList.add(?);// what do i put over here?

}
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

Point pointOne = new Point(x,y);
Point pointTwo = new Point(x+25,y);
Point pointThree = new Point(x+25,y+5);
Point pointFour = new Point(x,y+5);
points.add(pointOne );
points.add(pointTwo );
points.add(pointThree );
points.add(pointFour);



Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(pointOne.x, pointOne.y);
path.lineTo(pointTwo.x, pointTwo.y);
//and so on
path.close();

//and then
pList.add(points);
```

Comment: Use [PointF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF.html)

Comment: you have been a great help!
This method would be tedious if my path objects are complicated with many points coordinates right?

Comment: That's correct , you could also iterate through your points list `for(int i=1;i<points.size();i++){`to handle many points

Answer (score 0):

Since `Path` cannot be iterated you better use it as object of output nature, so basically you should initially fill `ArrayList` with points and when use this `ArrayList` to construct path or even create separate function for that.